# help with shell script for finding and moving files based on condition

Tags: shell, unix

Looking for some help with my bash script. I am trying to write this shell script to do the following:

1. find files in a dir named: 
   `server1-date.done`
   `server2-date.done`
   `server3-date.done` 
   `...`
   `server10-date.done`
2. print to a `listA`
3. find files in a dir (*.gz) and print to a `listB`
4. if `listA` has a count of `10` (basically found 10 `.done` files), then
   proceed with the moving the files in `listB` to its new directory
5. after moving the files from `listB`, then remove the old directory which is similarly named (`server1-date`, `server2-date`, ...) and the .done files.

So far, I have this in the works. I can't get the condition for the `if` section working. I don't think I coded that correctly. Any code suggestions, improvements, etc would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#Directories
GZDIR=/mydumps/mytest
FINALDIR=/mydumps/mytest/final
FLGDIR=/backup/mytest/flags
export GZDIR FINALDIR FLGDIR

#lists
FLGLIST="/mydumps/mytest/lists/userflgs.lst"
GZLIST="/mydumps/mytest/lists/gzfiles.lst"
export FLGLIST GZLIST

#Find files
find $FLGDIR -name \*.done -print > $FLGLIST
find $GZDIR -name \*.gz -print > $GZLIST

#Get need all (10) flags found before we do the move
FLG_VAL =`cat $FLGLIST | wc -l`
export $FLG_VAL

if [ "$FLG_VAL" = "10" ]; then
   for FILE in $GZLIST
       do
       echo "mv $GZLIST $FINALDIR" 2>&1
          for FLAG in $FLGLIST
             do
             echo "rmdir -f $FLAG" 2>&1
             done
       done
       else
           echo "Cannot move file" 2>&1
      exit 0
fi
```

Comment: `export $FLG_VAL` is both completely unnecessary, and also likely doesn't do anything even close to what you think it's doing.

Comment: There's no need to export any of those variables (or, indirectly, their contents).

Comment: Is there a way you to check to all your syntax prior to execution?

Comment: By the way, there is very little need for adding `2>&1` at the end of echo commands since it is (almost?) impossible for echo to fail. Perhaps you meant `1>&2` to have the messages printed on stderr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this will work, but it will fix all the obvious problems:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Directories
GZDIR=/mydumps/mytest
FINALDIR=/mydumps/mytest/final
FLGDIR=/backup/mytest/flags
export GZDIR FINALDIR FLGDIR

#lists
FLGLIST="/mydumps/mytest/lists/userflgs.lst"
GZLIST="/mydumps/mytest/lists/gzfiles.lst"

#Find files
find "$FLGDIR" -name '*.done' -print > "$FLGLIST"
find "$GZDIR" -name '*.gz' -print > "$GZLIST"

#Get need all (10) flags found before we do the move
FLG_VAL=$(wc -l <"$FLGLIST")  # Always prefer $( ... ) to backticks.

if [ "$FLG_VAL" -ge 10 ]; then
    for FILE in $(cat "$GZLIST")
        do
        echo "mv $FILE $FINALDIR" 2>&1
    done
    for FLAG in $(cat "$FLGLIST")
        do
        echo "rmdir -f $FLAG" 2>&1
    done
else
    echo "Cannot move file" 2>&1
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: I have to remove both `.done` flag and the directory too: `rm -f /mydumps/mytest/flags/server1-20110311.done` and  `rmdir -f /mydumps/mytest/flags/server1-20110311`. Can I do this in the same for loop??

Comment: @jdamae - Yes, you can. :-) It's not very hard, and I will leave exactly how to do it for you to puzzle over for awhile.

Comment: i figured it out. i used `ls` to get a listing of the dirs and removed them after moving the files over.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I really recommend that you as the default approach always [test for exceptions](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20930447/index.html), and do not include the "normal" case inside a test unless that is necessary.

```
...
FLG_VAL=`wc -l < $FLGLIST`              # no need for cat, and no space before '='
export $FLG_VAL

if [ "$FLG_VAL" != "10" ]; then
      echo "Cannot move file" 2>&1
      exit 0
fi

for FILE in $GZLIST
do
    echo "mv $GZLIST $FINALDIR" 2>&1
    for FLAG in $FLGLIST
    do
         echo "rmdir -f $FLAG" 2>&1
    done
done
```

See how much easier the code is to read now that the error check is extracted and stands by itself?

Comment: yes, thanks for your suggestions. always looking for best practices.

Answer (score 1):

```
FLG_VAL =`cat $FLGLIST | wc -l`
```

Should be:

```
FLG_VAL=`cat $FLGLIST | wc -l`
```

Comment: Better: `FLG_VAL=$(wc -l < "$FLGLIST")`